# How to set up the angular child routing correctly

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to set up child paths, but when navigating, the path turns out to be the wrong one

I have a cabinet module and these are its routers

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CabinetComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: RouteCabinetPath.DASHBOARD,
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

```
export enum RouteCabinetPath {
  CABINET = 'cabinet',
  DASHBOARD = 'dashboard',
}
```

I want to make sure that I have paths to the cabinet itself **/cabinet** and **/cabinet/dashboard**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a feature module that is (probably) lazy loaded, the `/cabinet`-part of your routes will be located in the `AppRoutingModule`:

```
{path: 'cabinet', loadChildren: () => ...CabinetModule }
```

Here in the `CabinetRoutingModule` you will need to define two routes:

```
[
  {path: '', component: CabinetComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => ...DashboardModule}
]
```

or if you want to embed those two routes into your `CabinetComponent` you could add a child route with an empty route

```
{path: '', component: CabinetComponent,
 children: [
    {path: '', component: CabinetDetailsComponent},
    {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => ...DashboardModule
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change         path: '' to         path: 'cabinet',

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'cabinet',
        component: CabinetComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: RouteCabinetPath.DASHBOARD,
            loadChildren: () => import('./pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
          },
        ]
      }
    ];
```